Applying l'Hôpital's rule to a limit defining a derivative
Today I was given this limit to solve:
$$\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\tag1$$
I used l'Hôpital's rule and got $nx^{n-1}$. However, I was pointed out that I cannot use l'Hôpital's rule here, since in order to do that I would have to know that th derivative of $x^n$ is $nx^{n-1}$ already, and in order to know that I would have to evaluate that limit.
Now, is there really no way around? Can't you prove the statement $\frac d{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}$ in other ways, for example by induction (yes, I do understand that it wouldn't work anymore if we let $n\in\Bbb R$.) Does the product rule implicitly make use of the limit $(1)$ to calculate $\frac d{dx}x^nx$?

It's more so that l'Hopital's is complete overkill. For natural n yes you can prove the derivative of x^n with the product rule, but then why would you use l'Hoptials? By finding (x^n)' you already know the value of the limit. So it's more that it's never necessary for such limits.

You can just factor the numerator.

Follow Paul's advice. That's by far the most elementary approach.

@altwoa I mean by induction, like $\frac d{dx}x^1=1=1x^0$ and $\frac d{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}\implies\frac d{dx}x^{n+1}=\frac d{dx}x^nx=x^n+x(nx^{n-1})=(n+1)x^n$.

@Elvis I know what you mean. But if you know the derivative is nx^n-1 by induction, then that's by definition the value of the limit - so why use l'Hopitals?

@altwoa ohh, well that's true. Maybe you don't notice that.

@Elvis well, technically speaking, the proof by induction works at least for $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ (you only have to apply the induction step in both directions).

Applying L’Hopital’s rule to ratios that are just limit def of derivative… cringe! I would say!

The product rule is valid for the product of any two differentiable functions, so it does not in any way rely on (1).
You can compute the derivative of $x^n$ in other ways:
(i) using algebra, $x^n - a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a + \cdots + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1})$. So when $x \not= a$ we have
$$
\frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a} = x^{n-1} + x^{n-2}a + \cdots + xa^{n-2} + a^{n-1}.
$$
Each term on the right side has limit $a^{n-1}$ as $x \to a$, and there are $n$ terms, so the right side has limit $na^{n-1}$ as $x \to a$.
(ii) set $x = a + h$, so $x \to a$ is the same as $h \to 0$. Thus
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(a+h)^n - a^n}{h}, 
$$
and we can write the numerator on the right side in a second way by the binomial theorem:
$$
(a+h)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}h^{k} \Longrightarrow (a+h)^n - a^n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}h^{k} = na^{n-1}h + \cdots,
$$
so
$$
\frac{(a+h)^n-a^n}{h} = \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n}{k}a^{n-k}h^{k-1} =  na^{n-1} + \cdots, 
$$
where the $n-1$ suppressed terms on the right all have positive powers of $h$. Thus
$$
\lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(a+h)^n - a^n}{h} = na^{n-1}.
$$

Ok, so proving it by induction wouldn't be wrong if $n\in\Bbb N$?

Why do you think it could be wrong to prove $(x^n)' = nx^{n-1}$ by induction on $n$?

My concern was just what I said in the answer: maybe the proof of the product rule in that case uses that limit in some way. But you said it doesn't, so I'm reassured now. Thanks.

Don't trust me: just check on your own what the proof of the product rule involves to see what the proof depends on.

We have $$L=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n-a^n}{x-a}\tag1
$$ $$\implies \displaystyle L=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^n\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^n\right)}{x\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)\right)}$$
$$\implies \displaystyle L=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{x^{n-1}\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)^n\right)}{\left(1-\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)\right)}$$
Now by using the concept of sum of a Geometric Progession we can say that $$L=\lim_{x\to a}\left(x^{n-1}\left(1+\frac{a}{x}+\frac{a^2}{x^2}+\cdots+\frac{a^{n-1}}{x^{n-1}}\right)\right)$$ $$\implies \boxed{L=na^{n-1}}$$
